# How do you represent a SOP in terms of NAND?

Tags: digital-logic, logic-gates

Is there a specific technique to convert SOPs to NAND.

I have the following expression:

A'BC + ABC'

And would like to represent it using **only** NAND gates.

A'BC=(((AB')')'C')'

ABC'=(((A'B')')'C')'

But now, how can you represent the or part using NAND gate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Do following procedure:**

Step 1: Convert all NOT-operators

Step 2: Convert all AND-operators (left to right)

Step 3: Convert all OR-operators (left to right)

**How to do it?:**

Convert NOT-operator: `X¯=X⊕X`

Convert AND-operator: `X⋅Y=(X⊕Y)⊕(X⊕Y)`

Convert OR-operator: `X+Y=(X⊕X)⊕(Y⊕Y)`